# How can I replicate a field from data now to data

Tags: sql, datagrip

I need to fill a table with some fields from another table, but one of the fields is populated via "DATE default NOW()" and the other just contains a DATE (the table that doesn't contain "DATE default NOW()" is already created, so I can't create another).

The field "DATE default NOW()" is populated each time that an ETL runs as a log of when the ETL completed successfully (so i can't change that format either).

How can I replicate the field populated by "DATE default NOW()" with the same date that shows in that field without changing the content of the field?

I'm working with DataGrip btw.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've read two times and I didn't understand what you want

Comment: I need to fill a table with the date that's already in the table, but I can't because of  "DATE default NOW()"

Comment: Why default value is bothering you? What are you doing in particular? Please, show the script